# Log out URL returns 503, redirects to path with double slash

Tags: users

When users access /user/logout they receive a "Page Not Found" error, and the URL they are forwarded to looks like this:

https://wwws.site.com/dir/site_name//dir/site_name/

Why is this redirect happening and how do I change the logout path so that it wouldn't create the double slash?

Comment: Did you create "logout" as custom link or displaying link of "user menu"?

Comment: I'm displaying the standard logout link of the "user menu"

Comment: Then it should work properly. I think, there is some other issue, not related to url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [URL()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7) to create logout url. For example,

url('user/logout')